# How can I delete text in a textarea in such a way that it gets entered in the native edit history?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a sort of mini-app that, amongst other things, manually modifies an input textarea. Simply setting the value (and optionally restoring cursor/scroll position) has one big drawback: it scrambles the edit history. So I use this function for all modifications:

```
function type(el, str) {
    var e = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
    e.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, null, str);
    el.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

The poor support is OK for my project, and the function works great for inserting text and for replacing it (select the text you want replaced, then call `type`). But when it's called with an empty string, it does nothing at all.

For some deletions I can work around this by selecting both the text I want to delete and something extra, re-typing the extra bit, then moving the cursor appropriately. But that's impossible if we're deleting everything in the textarea.

So does anybody know of a workaround, or some other way to modify the textarea's value without messing up the edit history?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing in an empty string, pass in `\0`. That seemed to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xKDrg/). Or you can just detect an empty string like this:

```
function type(el, str) {
    var e = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
    e.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, null, str || "\0");
    el.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: Looks like, in some browsers at least, the null character still exists, it's just invisible. See [http://jsfiddle.net/xKDrg/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/xKDrg/1/) - the "empty" textarea's length is 1.

Comment: It's better than nothing I guess. Does it work for this purpose?

Comment: Definitely better than nothing, and thanks for contributing it. It does work, but I'd feel better about my solution if it didn't insert extra characters. And I think I've found something - I put it in a separate answer.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, my solution doesn't work - though it's very sneaky about not working.

Comment: @st-boost In what way did it fail?

Comment: I think it failed because the history is stored differentially, and modifying the value messed up the anchor points, or something. What happened was I used my technique it to go from 4 spaces to nothing. It worked fine if the only content was 4 spaces. But if there was content before the spaces I was removing, then after I pressed ctrl-z the last character of that content was duplicated (in this case, it should have re-inserted 4 spaces, but instead inserted a newline and then the 4 spaces).

Comment: @st-boost I think I may have come up with a solution. What if you used my solution above, then selected the last character, then deleting it artificially with a KeyboardEvent?

Comment: Deleting is the problem - if I fire a textInput event with an empty string, nothing happens. Do you mean use a keyboardEvent instead? If so, could you provide an example? [It doesn't seem to be able to change the textarea's value](http://jsfiddle.net/d8Mkt/).

Comment: @st-boost Never mind, I think it just calls the event. What about, for example, when you post an answer to a question on SO and you use the format buttons. You can still undo everything. Does that use the same method your answer before had?

Comment: @st-boost I've just looked at the source of SO's, and what they do is use an artificial redo/undo. They prevent default actions when pressing ctrl+z/y and take care of it themselves using an array. I'll make a fiddle if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I can do that myself. I'm just hoping to get this working, because if I do my own history it would either break with context menu actions, or I would need to re-make the whole context menu and everything on it (some of which, like customizations added by extensions, would be impossible to detect or duplicate).

Comment: I could, but it would be impossible to make it as good as the native implementation. Also, have you tested the keyboardevents technique? I've spent hours looking into this and come across many examples that people say work just fine, and don't work for me, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qtPcF/34/). I'm beginning to think it's OS-related (I'm on OSX).

Comment: I'm on OSX also, it definitely doesn't type anything. I think for security reasons it's not supposed to but I may try on my Windows later